# How can we format and re-install android on micromax canvas phone to remove virus because factory reset don't help to remove virus?

Tags: formatting

My micromax canvas is full of viruses. I have tried to do factory reset. but it doesn't work out. as i start internet on phone, it automatically start installing application and block so many other applications. and popup with porn content.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! For a starter, please take a look at our [rom-flashing tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info), and follow the links collected there.

Answer (score -1):

The viruses may be coming from your SD card or the wireless router. So, remove the SD card and disable wireless when you reset the phone. Use mobile data (telecom) Internet, instead of your wireless connection, to activate Google Play and install an antivirus from the play store.